# Setup Root of SVN Server to be viewable from Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am new to the SVN Server side piece (have used it on the client side for a while). I have everything setup and I can commit and update no problem but I have a question. Is there a way to make the "root" of the SVN server view-able from Tortoise SVN? What I mean is when you go into Repo-Browse, is there a way to pull up all the Repositories at once? I imagine a quick way is to have one repository and put all of your projects in there, but wouldn't that mess up the versioning? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the "root" of the SVN server view-able from Tortoise SVN?

No, at least before 1.8 (there it's a planned feature)

> I imagine a quick way is to have one repository and put all of your projects in there, but wouldn't that mess up the versioning?

Yes, it will - because revisions are repository-wide and you'll share one line of numbering between all projects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there some way for me to get the functionality I am looking for? I find it very inconvenient to have to memorize all the Repository Names when I want to Repo-Browse in.

Comment: @IsaacLevin: For now - only browser in REPO-ROOT URL

Comment: Sad day... I guess I will wait for 1.8. Thanks

Comment: @IsaacLevin - maybe, [Create a shortcut to a repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-repo-shortcut.html) will help: you can start RepoBrowser with predefined repository selected

Answer (score 0):

before setting up SVN you need: 1.Install Putty http://www.putty.org/ 2.Creat Droplet on Digital Ocean 3.Install Apache,Install PHP,Install phpMyAdmin

after that follow steps on below link:

https://progtec.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/how-to-setup-svn-server/